# Spring WebClient and longpolling

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I want to use Spring's reactive WebClient to poll a REST endpoint that uses long-polling.

The endpoint provides messages for a chat-channel. When I call it and there is no message, it blocks (i.e. does not return) until a message appears (or 30 seconds pass).

So, in a synchronous world, I would dedicate a thread to monitor this channel, call the endpoint via RestTemplate, wait for the result, write it to a shared queue and start the next request. A consumer can then react to new items appearing on the queue.

In the reactive world, this is a bit different. Ideally, the consumer would subscribe to a Flux of messages. The question is how to construct this Flux.

The logic should be:

```
Mono<String> message = WebClient.get(). […] .bodyToMono(String.class);
// When the mono completes, create a new one just as described above
// Combine all of the monos into a Flux
flux.subscribe(message -> System.out.println("New message" + message);
```

I think that I need some kind of `switch…` operator but I can find the correct one.

Comment: You can just use `repeat`, i.e `WebClient.get(). […] .bodyToMono(String.class).repeat()`, will give you a flux of the replies, and will only start the next one when the previous is done.

Comment: @123 Yes, this is it! Do you mind writing an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: On phone, feel free to post it yourself though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @123 pointed out:

> You can just use repeat, i.e `WebClient.get(). […] .bodyToMono(String.class).repeat()`, will give you a flux of the replies, and will only start the next one when the previous is done.

Actually, what is required here is `defer()` and `repeat()`: `defer()` takes a supplier of Monos and `repeat()` will re-subscribe to the Mono upon completion of the previous subscription. That will cause the supplier to be called again and thus a new http request will be started.

Also, since this runs forever, it will lead to an unclean application shutdown: If a shutdown occurs, there is probably an http request in flight. To cleanly end the Flux, `takeUntilOther()` can be used, which takes another Publisher (like an `EmitterProcessor`). Then, in a `@PreDestroy` method, you can call `shutdown.onNext(true)`, which will cause the http request to be cancelled.

My solution now looks like this:

```
   Mono.defer(() -> receiveMessage())
   .repeat()
   .takeUntilOther(shutdown)
   .subscribe(message -> System.out.println("New message" + message);
```

Comment: Hi david, Is it the `defer()` call required? I used your solution without `defer` and it believe it works `priceIndexService.getPriceIndexOnRealTime().map(Objects::toString).repeat().takeUntilOther(shutdown.asFlux()).., where `priceIndexService.getPriceIndexOnRealTime()` returns the webclient Mono<T> response

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly you should be able to solve this by sth like

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
    .flatMap(counter -> WebClient.get().[…].bodyToMono(String.class))
    .subscribe(message -> System.out.println("New message" + message))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this only works for actual polling but not for long polling with blocking requests.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks for the reply.